# Save source code as rendered for client as .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html, save

I'm trying to save the source code of a webpage as it is rendered for the client/user. Not as the code is stored on the server, but as it looks after scripts have executed client-side. (If that makes any sense). Basically taking the source code as it would look if the client where to open a source code viewer, and then save that code using PHP as a .txt file on the server. I'm thinking some javascript/HTML5? (And of course PHP)

Comment: If you want to programmatically save a page after performing some client-side actions then you may want to look into [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) instead of PHP. These tools are very good at web scraping.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to cache the html output.  You can do that with the `ob_` functions in PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start();  //start buffering output

// your html and echo statements

$cachefile = //wherever you want to save it

$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); /* save the buffer to cache file */
fclose($fp);

ob_end_flush(); /* Send the buffer to the browser */
?>
```

Comment: You can use this as a cache by adding some code to check for existence of $cachefile under certain conditions before doing ob_start() and then doing `include($cachefile); exit;` to just return the cached file rather than rebuild it all.

Comment: Only problem is... I have a Facebook social plugin (javascript) and i want the executed result of that javascript code to be save, but currently it don't.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that. Javascript is executed in the browser, and even with view source in the browser it doesn't show you the updates that javascript did to the page, only the HTML as it first came to the client.

Comment: I can't believe that it's not possible! The client can see what the source code looks like afterwards, so how come you not client-side cache it and server-side save it?!?